# How to populate a node reference field that has multiple values?

Tags: entities, rules

I'm using the rules to create a new node upon changing the current node publishing status to published. And populate some field based on the updated node field. Im trying to populate a node reference field in the new created node based on the node reference field multiple values from updated node. I wasn't able to use the tokens since it returns single value. How do I get all the values using tokens and return the values in an array (using the php code)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get multiple value node reference field using the Array Tokens module, an extension to the Token module, providing tokens for multiple-value CCK fields and taxonomy terms.

```
$authors = array([node:field_op_author-default-array-nid]);
$options = array();

foreach ($authors as $author) {
  $options[] = array('nid'=>$author);
}

return($options);
```